# Display data on frame buffer

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, java-native-interface, rgb

I have a rooted android device and in my native code i have pointer to a buffer that holds the pixel data. Now my task is dump this pixel data onto the frame buffer in order to display it. I'm very new to linux environment so i hardly have information regarding the same. I googled and found that ioctl() may help but didnt find more details about the same.

If someone has worked on a similar requirement and issue please provide some links or answers. Also any suggestion to do the same shall be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the learn curve for android hardware and video software, you may want to review these links, one kind of a long mp4 but they are pretty relevant to understand the area u work in.

[one](http://marakana.com/static/courseware/android/Aptina-Android-Camera-Internals.pdf)

[two](http://video.linux.com/videos/exposing-the-android-camera-stack)